# Show specific row php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am a terrible php noob and I have a question about reading out specific data from my table.

I have this table set up with a few data fields.

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | description | img   |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | sdkfhkjsh   | 2.png |
|  2 | isoaskdlja  | 3.png |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

etc..

How can I read out and show only the data the row with ID 1?
I have this small HTML set up and It works but only reads out my complete table.

```
  <?php
include("Connect.php");
$command = "SELECT * FROM shangxia_tshirts ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($command);
?>
<?
while($columns = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
        <div class="tile">
        <img src="styling/img/t-shirts/<? echo $columns['img']; ?>.png">
            <div class="inside_tile">
            <div class="price_basket"><h1><? echo $columns['title']; ?></h1> </div>
            <div class="price"><h1><? echo $columns['price']; ?></h1> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM shangxia_tshirts WHERE id = 1` Go get a basic book on SQL. _Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes_ is a good starter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$command = "SELECT * FROM shangxia_tshirts WHERE id = '1' ORDER BY id ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

just modify the SQL query

```
$command = "SELECT * FROM shangxia_tshirts WHERE ID=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it in the query if that is the only one you need to display.

Why load data when not needed?

```
$command = "SELECT * FROM shangxia_tshirts where id=1 ORDER BY id ASC";
```